# regex a string, convert to number and match condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
002 2.0 (100aa) 95-97
```

I then want `regex` the `95-97` portion of it and paste it with relevant two numbers so I get a year.
In example, `96-97` should become `1995-1997`, **but** `00-05` should become `2000-2005` (all numbers between `0` and `16` should be pasted with `20`, but all other numbers with `19`).

Then, when I have i.e. `1995-1997` I want to check if a year (i.e. `1996`) is present inside `1995-1997` interval or not, and return a bolean. 
How would one wright such code?

Best Regards

Comment: show us your efforts so far please

Comment: If you just have that string, there is no need to regex, just take the parts you need. But I suspect this is not the only string, so please adapt your question and indicate what the static and variable part is, and show what you have tried, and where your attempts failed.

Comment: If the hyphen is only appearing in the last part, what's the problem with finding it?

Comment: and how should be considered the following pair `16-05`? should it be `2016-2005` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest There are no such pairs. :)

Comment: if so, for this goal "to check if current year (2016) is present inside" it would be enough to check if the last part is `16`. Otherwise, I don't see much sense in your task, I'm voting to close this question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest But if I have `95-97` and want to check if `1996` is present inside `95-97`?

Comment: You have specified only this condition "I want to check if current year (2016) " in your question. Add more context and conditions to your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Updated:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the callback variant of `replace`:

```js
function parseString(str) {
    function padYear(year) {
        return year <  30 ? 2000+year : 
               year < 100 ? 1900+year : year;
    }
    var result = {};
    result.hasCurrentYear = false;
    result.str = str.replace(/(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/g, function (match, yr1, yr2) {
        yr1 = padYear(+yr1);
        yr2 = padYear(+yr2);
        var yrNow = (new Date).getFullYear();
        result.hasCurrentYear = yrNow >= yr1 && yrNow <= yr2;
        return yr1 + '-' + yr2;
    });
    
    return result;
}

var str = '002 2.0 (100aa) 95-16';
console.log(parseString(str));
```

Note that I made the split at year 30, as the solution will become outdated soon if you use 16 as split year.

Comment: You're welcome. Just note a minor correction inside the replace callback. It should read `result.hasCurrentYear ` with the `result` prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's a much simpler way to check if a certain year is in "range".
The solution using `String.split`, `Array.map` functions and `Number` constructor:

```
var str = "002 2.0 (100aa) 95-97";

function checkYearInRange(str, year) {
    year = Number(year);
    var range = str.split(" ").pop().split('-').map((v) => Number((Number(v) > 16)? "19"+v : "20"+v));
    return (range[0] <= year && year <= range[1]);
}

console.log(checkYearInRange(str, "1996"));  // true
console.log(checkYearInRange(str, "2015"));  // false
```